# Printing only the answer to the api response

Tags: python, string, api

Please may someone teach me how I would print Only the answer and not the other part of the string? 
p.s I'm fairly new to python

```
import requests

url = "https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/quickAnswer"

querystring = {"q":"how many calories in a banana%3F"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "193d0f135bmshc98650dc5767038p13ec93jsndad818d5e25e"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(response.json()['answer'])`

You can also change your request to `requests.get(url, ...` instead of `requests.request("GET", url, ...`

Comment: I want to print only the part where it says how many calories there are in a banana and not the rest of the string. if that makes sense

Comment: My bad, fixed the code, try this...

Comment: Oh my god thank you!